# Should basement staircase door have a passage or privacy knob?

Tags: doors, interior

I am replacing a door knob on first level that opens to staircase to the basement. Should this door have a passage or privacy knob?
Thanks!

Comment: "Passage" as in non-locking vs "privacy" as in locking? Where on Earth are you located? There may be different code that impacts what you do. If you go with locking, you'd better be able to unlock from downstairs, or have an alternate exit - you don't want someone trapped in the basement in case of fire or flooding.

Comment: @freeman Passage as in pul and open. Privacy, as in keyless lock with a push of a button/twist of a small knob, etc, with pin override, liken in bathrooms. Sorry these are common terms by door knob manufacturers and I presumed it would be clear. Location USA.

Comment: I did presume correctly, but clarity never hurts.

Comment: This is completely a matter of opinion and the nuances of the situation. VTC. That said, I don't think I've ever seen a privacy latch on a stairway door.

Comment: @isherwood, in my previous  (built 2002) house, I has a door that would lock with a key, to the basement.

Comment: That's not a privacy latch. That's a security latch.

Comment: @isherwood, right, I didn’t say it was a privacy latch, I was just pointing out that it wasn’t passage. I should’ve been clear.

Comment: I put a privacy lock on mine when kids were small the button on the stair side.   This kept kids from opening and tumbling down the stairs.  Also kept a “key” on top of trim so adults could easily open as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can install either by code....in fact you don’t even need a door.

However, a landing is required at the top of those stairs, if the door swings outward over the stairs. (See ICC R311.5.4) If that’s the case and no landing is provided, I’d put a “keyed lock set” on that door so no one accidentally uses the door, until you can fix the door swing or just remove the door. (No door...no landing required.)